# jquery load once

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lnk').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#content").load(this.href);
    });

});
</script>

<a href="http://google.com" id="lnk">Google</a>
<a href="http://gmail.com" id="lnk">Gmail</a>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

When I click the first link (google) it works and load content to my content div.  However, when I click second link (gmail) it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me understand this behavior?

Comment: Neither of them work. :X

Comment: Your HTML is not VALID ! Why same ID for 2 elements ?

Comment: why save the href in your `url` variable and then not use it on the very next line? And element ids must be unique, you might want to switch to class

Comment: As MrOBrian said, switch from Id to class tags, and change your selector to match.

Comment: as i sad, im a noob. it works now. thank you for answer and help.

Comment: Valid html will not circumvent same-origin policy

Comment: Wait, it works now? It definitely should not, as per cross-origin security policy… in what way does it now "work"? Or are the Google and Gmail examples just placeholders and it's actually loading local content?

Comment: yes gogle and gmail is pilaceholders. load some local asdf.html files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are unique, you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID (`$('#lnk')` will get the 1st element).  Use classes instead

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lnk').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").load(this.href);
    });

});
</script>

<a href="http://google.com" class="lnk">Google</a>
<a href="http://gmail.com" class="lnk">Gmail</a>
```

Also, this will not work, as you cannot use `.load` to load arbitrary URLs.  That's called the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is attaching the event to the first thing that has the ID you specified, as the document should only have one element with that ID. Try this instead:

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lnk').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").load(this.href);
    });

});
</script>

<a href="http://google.com" class="lnk">Google</a>
<a href="http://gmail.com" class="lnk">Gmail</a>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks all of you guys. As i said im a noob and i guess i learn very slowly :) Thank you everyone, again.

Comment: No problem. I just updated it a little bit to switch to the new on() syntax.